# GDB hangs when running 32bit executables

Tags: gdb

I have a VM with Mint Cinnamon 19.2 (this also happens in Ubuntu 18.04):

whenever I run a 32 bit executable, whether i put breakpoints or not, I get these kind of warnings:

```
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xf7fd9be0 to 0xfffffffff7fd9be0.
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xf7fda195 to 0xfffffffff7fda195.
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xf7fdbd1c to 0xfffffffff7fdbd1c.
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xf7fdb924 to 0xfffffffff7fdb924.
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xf7fe99b3 to 0xfffffffff7fe99b3.
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xf7fea401 to 0xfffffffff7fea401.
warning: Breakpoint address adjusted from 0xf7fea706 to 0xfffffffff7fea706.
```

And then the program hangs and the only thing I can do is send a SIGINT (Ctrl+C)

I have to mention that on Kali it doesn't happen, so maybe I'm missing some dependencies or something?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a duplicate of [gdb can't debug the 32bits program for linux](https://superuser.com/q/1487122/398791) (I don't have enough rep to flag this as duplicate.)

I've hit the same bug and discuss a couple of workarounds in reply to the question above, see here: https://superuser.com/a/1489686/398791